# How to have certain WordPress settings set by default on a per author basis

Tags: author, author-template

I have a WP author who always needs to change various settings when creating a new post:

1. Display author box (post format)
2. Display last updated (post format)
3. Select 'News' category (categories)
4. Select article type 'news article' (Post SEO Settings for The SEO Framework plugin)

How could it be possible to have these things 'on' by default for only this one author?

Answer (score 0):

To check if s/he is the right author, you can use `is_author()` function using the author id or name as parameter. And, depending on how you set up the settings for displaying author box or last updated. You can put your settings.

I am considering your settings are in options table. So I will use `

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author('4') ){
  update_option( 'display_author_box', true );
}
```

If you want to show him customized posts, you can do that with a query.

Hope this helps.

References:
[is_author() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/)
[update_option() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)